# What is the point of ValueTask.Preserve()?

Tags: c#, async-await, valuetask

`ValueTask` and `ValueTask<TResult>` have a `Preserve()` method which is summarized as "Gets a ValueTask that may be used at any point in the future."

What does that mean and when should we use it? Does it imply that a 'normal' `ValueTask` can't be used "at any point in the future"? If so, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`ValueTask`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/) is a performance optimization over a [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task)s, but this performance comes with a cost: You cannot use a `ValueTask` as freely as a `Task`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask#remarks) mentions these restrictions:

> The following operations should never be performed on a `ValueTask` instance:
>
> - Awaiting the instance multiple times.
> - Calling [`AsTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.astask) multiple times.
> - Using more than one of these techniques to consume the instance.

These restrictions apply only for `ValueTask`s that are backed by a `IValueTaskSource`. A `ValueTask` can also be backed by a `Task`, or by a `TResult` value (for a `ValueTask<TResult>`). If you know with 100% certainty that a `ValueTask` is not backed by an `IValueTaskSource`, you can use it as freely as a `Task`. For example you can `await` is multiple times, or you can wait it synchronously to complete with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

In general you don't know how a `ValueTask` is implemented internally, and even if you know (by studying the source code) you may not want to rely on an implementation detail. With the [`ValueTask.Preserve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.preserve) method you can create a new `ValueTask` that represents the original `ValueTask`, and can be used without restrictions because it's not baked by an `IValueTaskSource`. This method affects the original `ValueTask` only if it's backed by an `IValueTaskSource`, otherwise it's a no-op (it just returns the original task unaltered).

```
ValueTask preserved = originalValueTask.Preserve();
```

After calling `Preserve`, the original `ValueTask` has been consumed. It should no longer be awaited, or `Preserve`d again, or converted to `Task` with the `AsTask` method. Doing any of those actions is likely to result in an `InvalidOperationException`. But now you have the `preserved` representation of it, which can be used with the same freedom as a `Task`.

---

<sub>My answer included initially a practical example of using the `Preserve` method, which proved to be incorrect. This example can be found in the [4th revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71344625/4) of this answer.</sub>

Comment: If I understand correctly: If I don't await a ValueTask immediately and save it to a variable, but I also make sure I don't do anything to it except await it exactly once, I don't have to use Preserve(), and on the other hand, I should call Preserve() to ensure I can always safely await/AsTask() it multiple times if I need that.

Comment: @Petrusion yes, exactly. Normally you don't need to use the `Preserve`, because you just `await` the asynchronous method without storing the `ValueTask` in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation isn't very clear.  From [the source](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs) :

```
/// <summary>null if representing a successful synchronous completion, 
/// otherwise a <see cref="Task"/> or a <see cref="IValueTaskSource"/>.</summary>
internal readonly object? _obj;
```

`ValueTask` internally declares a nullable container object to hold either the `Task` or `IValueTaskSource` that the `ValueTask` encapsulates should it be a `ValueTask` that does so.  It is otherwise `null` if the `ValueTask` instead is representing a completion.

```
public ValueTask Preserve() => _obj == null ? this : new ValueTask(AsTask());
```

`Preserve()` returns a new `ValueTask` representing its underlying task in the case that the `ValueTask` represents a `Task` or an `IValueTaskSource` (ie: `_obj != null`) or otherwise just returns itself if the `ValueTask` represents a successful synchronous completion. It's necessary because `_obj` is internal and can't be tested externally.